# How to DELETE record from JDBC sink with Apache Flink?

Tags: apache-flink

reading some JSON data from Kafka, based on a value within the JSON. Is it possible to INSERT or DELETE a record from the JDBC sink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own sink via extending `RichSinkFunction`. Create the connection by JDBC in `open()` method, and execute CRUD statements in `invoke()` method.

Comment: Just a quick question would you suggest that if I pass a key with null to the sink then run a delete query? Or should a make a more specific Sink for my situation that analyzes the JSON?